# One-off creation with the Factory Pattern

Tags: design-patterns

I'm putting together a game whilst trying to conform to various design patterns, the factory design pattern is one of them.

There are certain game elements that get created constantly e.g. enemies, bullets. Then there are elements that only get instantiated one time, like background element for instance.

In cases when you're only doing one-off creations of objects, is there any point in using the factory design pattern? or would it be more appropriate to have a mixture of directly created objects and factory created ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using factory method, still makes sense for single instance objects.
The most basic reason is that you will end up with a more testable code.